# Is it possible to generate migration only for a part of model?

Tags: entity-framework, migration, entity-framework-migrations

I would like to generate migrations using custom VSIX plugin and only for a part of model. I found out I can filter generated code in class inherited from `CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator` by overridnig method `Generate(IEnumerable<MigrationOperation> operations, string @namespace, string className)`. I filtered operations for one table in this method.
I read that I should invoke `Add-Migration` for second time in Package Manager console when modifying the migration. I did it. Then updated database. When I created next migration for whole model, code for filtered table was not generated and I had to write code for previously filtered table by myself.

I thought that invoking `Add-Migration` method for second time when I made changes in migration file will look into migration code and make hash for model which will arise when I apply this migration.

EDIT:

I tried to call Add-Migration with -Force parameter and without -Force parameter. When I use -Force parameter migration code for Up/Down methods will be overriten if I made some additional changes in migration code. That´s why I think I shouldn´t use -Force parameter in this case.

My MigrationCodeGenerator is set correctly in Configuration constructor: CodeGenerator = new MigrationCodeGenerator(tables);

Code for MigrationCodeGenerator where I filter operations and do not generate indexes:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design;

namespace MyNamespace.Migrations
{
  public class MigrationCodeGenerator : CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Tables for which to generate migration file
    /// </summary>
    private List<string> Tables;

    public MigrationCodeGenerator(List<string> tables)
    {
      Tables = tables;
    }

    protected override void GenerateInline(CreateIndexOperation createIndexOperation, IndentedTextWriter writer) { }

    protected override void Generate(CreateIndexOperation createIndexOperation, IndentedTextWriter writer) { }

    protected override void Generate(DropIndexOperation dropIndexOperation, IndentedTextWriter writer) { }

    protected override string Generate(IEnumerable<MigrationOperation> operations, string @namespace, string className)
    {
      if (Tables != null)
      {
        List<MigrationOperation> filteredOperations = new List<MigrationOperation>();

        foreach (var operation in operations)
        {
          if (operation is CreateTableOperation)
          {
            CreateTableOperation createTableOperation = operation as CreateTableOperation;

            if (Tables.Contains(createTableOperation.Name))
              filteredOperations.Add(operation);
          }
          else if (operation is AddColumnOperation)
          {
            AddColumnOperation addColumnOperation = operation as AddColumnOperation;

            if (Tables.Contains(addColumnOperation.Table))
              filteredOperations.Add(operation);
          }
          else if (operation is AddPrimaryKeyOperation)
          {
            AddPrimaryKeyOperation addPrimaryKeyOperation = operation as AddPrimaryKeyOperation;

            if (Tables.Contains(addPrimaryKeyOperation.Table))
              filteredOperations.Add(operation);
          }
          else if (operation is AddForeignKeyOperation)
          {
            AddForeignKeyOperation addForeignKeyOperation = operation as AddForeignKeyOperation;

            if (Tables.Contains(addForeignKeyOperation.DependentTable))
              filteredOperations.Add(operation);
          }
          else if (operation is DropTableOperation)
          {
            DropTableOperation dropTableOperation = operation as DropTableOperation;

            if (Tables.Contains(dropTableOperation.Name))
              filteredOperations.Add(operation);
          }
          else if (operation is DropColumnOperation)
          {
            DropColumnOperation dropColumnOperation = operation as DropColumnOperation;

            if (Tables.Contains(dropColumnOperation.Table))
              filteredOperations.Add(operation);
          }
          else if (operation is DropPrimaryKeyOperation)
          {
            DropPrimaryKeyOperation dropPrimaryKeyOperation = operation as DropPrimaryKeyOperation;

            if (Tables.Contains(dropPrimaryKeyOperation.Table))
              filteredOperations.Add(operation);
          }
          else if (operation is DropForeignKeyOperation)
          {
            DropForeignKeyOperation dropForeignKeyOperation = operation as DropForeignKeyOperation;

            if (Tables.Contains(dropForeignKeyOperation.DependentTable))
              filteredOperations.Add(operation);
          }
          else if (operation is AlterColumnOperation)
          {
            AlterColumnOperation alterColumnOperation = operation as AlterColumnOperation;

            if (Tables.Contains(alterColumnOperation.Table))
              filteredOperations.Add(operation);
          }
          else if (operation is RenameColumnOperation)
          {
            RenameColumnOperation renameColumnOperation = operation as RenameColumnOperation;

            if (Tables.Contains(renameColumnOperation.Table))
              filteredOperations.Add(operation);
          }
          else if (operation is RenameTableOperation)
          {
            RenameTableOperation renameTableOperation = operation as RenameTableOperation;

            if (Tables.Contains(renameTableOperation.Name))
              filteredOperations.Add(operation);
          }
          else if (operation is SqlOperation)
          {
            filteredOperations.Add(operation);
          }
        }

        return base.Generate(filteredOperations, @namespace, className);
      }

      return base.Generate(operations, @namespace, className);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you called `Add-Migration` with `-Force`parameter? Did you registered your inherited `CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator` properly?

Comment: I edited first post with reply

Comment: Can you clarify your problem?

Comment: I work in a team of 5 people and everybody work on different modules in Entity Data Model Designer. We generate classes from edmx model using VSIX plugin. I would want to be able to generate migration files only for a part of model (to choose tables for which to generate migration) using this plugin. Everybody from our team would generate migration only for their own module. That is not possible right now because it always makes snapshot of whole current model which is saved to MigrationHistory table.

Comment: This is currently not possible. One option that might be viable for you might be to use different `DbContext`s for each part.